# mysql_query does not work partially when loading from sql file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have dumped the contents of a database in an sql file in a form like

```
insert into `a` values
(17,11,5),
(18,12,7),
(19,12,10),
(21,14,45),
(22,15,46),
(24,16,46),
(25,16,49),
(26,17,21),
(27,17,30),
(28,17,45),
(29,17,54),
(30,18,32),
(31,18,35),
(32,19,23),
(33,19,27),
(34,19,54),
(35,20,53),
(36,21,32),
(37,21,35),
(38,21,45),
(39,22,23),
(40,22,30),
(41,22,45),
(57,24,19),
(58,25,46),
(59,26,39),
(60,27,49),
(61,27,56),
(62,28,34);

insert into `b` values (14,'2009-01-06',''),
(15,'2009-02-01',''),
(16,'2009-03-01',''),
(17,'2009-03-25',''),
(18,'2009-04-05',''),
(19,'2009-04-17',''),
(20,'2009-04-18',''),
(21,'2009-04-19',''),
(22,'2009-04-23',''),
(24,'2009-07-05',''),
(25,'2009-08-02',''),
(26,'2009-08-07',''),
(27,'2009-09-06',''),
(28,'2009-09-14','');

etc..
```

I have 4 such tables with no foreigh key constrains. Then I try to upload the data into the db (mysql). I read the file's contents, I pass each table's insertion into an array and then i do mysql_query for each element :

```
$sqlArray = explode(';',$sqlFile); 

 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sqlArray);$i++){
   mysql_query($sqlArray[$i]) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());;
 }
```

The result is that the last three tables are inserted but the first one is not, and the error is :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' insert into `a` values (17,11,5), (18,12,7), (19,12,10), (21,14,4' at line 1
```

I validated that the $sqlArray has the correct contains and the queries are correct and runnable from phpmyadmin.

The problem seems to be regardless of the first table (i.e. it will show up even if `b` was first) and it always seems to "cut" the query in the middle (or after almost 70 characters).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried putting ' into (17,11,5). i.e ('17','11','5'), as far as i can remember you need them values to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: why not do that at the command line, e.g. `mysql yourdb < file.sql`?

Comment: magicianlam : I'll try it but the strange thing is that the sql query is valid. It has no problem from within phpmyadmin.

Comment: marc b : I want this to be done from a web environment and from windows ;)

Comment: What is your database structure for table `a` ? What are the datatype for the columns ?

Comment: how do you read the sql file from disk?

Comment: Philippe : they are int(10) unsigned,int(10),int(10). The problem is that if I put `b` first in the file, the same error occurs..

Comment: didierc : By input, type file. The reading is correct, I validated it by echo-ing the contents i read.

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement has a typo ("int" should be "into"):

```
insert int `b` values (14,'2009-01-06',''),
```

Alternately, if that's not the issue, try using separate insert statements to get a clearer error message:

```
insert into `a` values (17,11,5);
insert into `a` values (118,12,7);
...
```

I have experienced on some older versions of MySQL that they don't like the extended inserts. You can also try specifying the column names explicitly with the real names of your columns. This would be useful if you have more than 3 columns in those tables (an auto-increment column for example).

```
insert into `a` (`[column1name]`, `[column2name]`, `[column3name]`) values (17,11,5);
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Thnx! (the typo was by mistake ;))